# drush make: Specify subdir for make-files provided by contrib modules

Tags: drush

Recently I started using `drush make` to pull in Drupal Core, all the required contrib-modules, themes and libraries.

One of the modules I use is the [geshifilter](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter)-module. This module comes with it's own make-files, so when I run `drush make` to build my entire site, `drush` sees this make-file and also builds that to pull in all the dependencies for the geshifilter-module.

While this is really convenient, I have one small problem with this: I prefer to have all the contrib-modules in `sites/all/modules/contrib`, so I define my modules like this:

```
projects[geshifilter][subdir] = "contrib"
```

However, the make-file inside geshifilter doesn't specify this subdir, so as a result, `drush` downloads the dependencies to just `sites/all/modules` instead of `sites/all/modules/contrib`.

For the moment I have added some commands in my wrapper-script around `drush make` to move those dependencies to the contrib-folder after `drush make` has finished, but I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to override the subdir-property for make-files which are provided by modules (obviously without manually modifying those make-files). I'm using drush 4.5 (default one from Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seems to be supported by Drush, you should consider [reporting a feature request](https://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drush). The existing "[Default path for projects, libraries](https://drupal.org/node/911722)" issue seems relevant too.

You may also consider reporting an issue for the GeSHi Filter module. Modules are not supposed to bundle a `.make` that download their dependencies. Usually, makefiles for modules are only used to download external libraries. The current makefile seems broken too since it download GeSHi as project while it should be downloaded as a library.

Comment: for some reason, adding the contrib to the module itself does not work, but adding it as default does: defaults[projects][subdir] = "contrib"

Answer (score 8):

You can specify a default subdir for all projects this way:

```
core = "7.x"
api = 2
defaults[projects][subdir] = contrib
projects[] = views
projects[] = ctools
```

it is a [very recent addition](http://drupal.org/node/1633050) to drush 5, only available in the dev release.

Answer (score 1):

here's a patch for the geshifilter make file to not interfere with your work flow
https://drupal.org/node/1948852#comment-7602129

Answer (score 0):

just a short notice for who it might concern:

chaining directories:

```
defaults[projects][subdir] = "contrib/projects"
```

or

```
projects[admin_menu][subdir] = "contrib/core"
```